# Is there a way of inspecting msg.value and msg.sender in remix IDE?

Tags: remix, contract-debugging

I'm playing with re-entrancy business: https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/reentrancy-attack-on-smart-contracts-how-to-identify-the-exploitable-and-an-example-of-an-attack-4470a2d8dfe4

Just curious if there is a way of inspecting `msg.value` in Remix?

Is it just me or maybe I'm missing something obvious...

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by inspecting?

Comment: inspecting = showing value, displaying the current state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the value to a public variable (in both cases) and then see the value of the variable. This makes sense for debugging only.

[image]

Comment: Nice little hack :)